# How to look at custom events older than 30 minutes in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I submitted custom events like this to GA4:

```
{
  "athlete_type": {
    "sport": "baseball",
    "role": "pitcher"
  }
}
```

I can see `athlete_type.sport` for the last 30 minutes under `Business objectives > Examine user behaviour > Events > [pick athlete_type from the table] > Events in last 30 minutes` as demonstrated in these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, it is not clear to me how I can look for analytics for `athlete_type.sport` for anything older than 30 minutes.  What did I do wrong?

---

EDIT

If for some reason I need to make a completely new graph/chart/visualization, then my goal is to see how many times each of `athlete_type`, `athlete_type.sport` and `athlete_type.role` was submitted per day on any given day.  Would be helpful to see screenshots and specific steps to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into `Admin >> Custom Defintions`and add those parameters as custom dimensions. Once you do that, wait a couple days and they will be available in Explorer and in Looker Studio datasets. If you have existing Looker reports, you will need to refresh the connection for them to appear as new fields.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! Can you provide screenshots showing a) how `athlete_type`, `athlete_type.sport` and `athlete_type.role` is associated with each `dimension` and b) which fields/buttons/switches to press in `Explorer` to see which `athlete_type`, `athlete_type.sport` and `athlete_type.role`  ?

Comment: Can't really show screenshots...You are already pushing the parameters to Google as evidence in your 30 minute looks. What you need to do is create the custom dimension(s) in Admin so you can use them in reports (i.e. they will be dimensions). In `Explorer`, create a freeform report. Under the `Dimensions` section, click the `+` and navigate to `custom`. All your new parameters will be there (you might need to wait 48hrs). Drag/Drop them into the rows/columns and apply the corresponding metric.

Comment: Hmm....I've been collecting custom events for over a month.  That's way more than 48 hours.  or are you saying it takes 48 hours to translate custom events to custom dimensions?  And would that also mean none of the custom events from last month will ever show again under custom dimensions in the Free Form reports?

Comment: You can collect all of this data for months and months and if you haven't setup the custom dimensions, it won't show. When you setup the dimensions, it will take <= 48 hours before you can use them or see data on it. Whether the old data will come over, I don't know. Your old events will still show there because those are events. The parameter you are sending however, probably won't be there until you create the dimensions. Hope this helps.